# Trying to get at list<x> from database and save it internally in my program. Getting ObjectContext errors

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have created an app (this is for a school project). That is to be connected to a database. All this works great thanks to Entity Framework.

The problem I'm encountering is the following.

I have a class of customers in my c# code. These `Customers` have `public virtual list<Accounts>`.

In the database I have the following tables, Customers and Accounts. 
The Account class has a property `public virtual Customer Customers {get; set;}`

I have a separate class that has a `list<Customer>` that I want to update from the database.

```
using (var db = new dbcontext())
{
    list<Customer> templist = new list<Customer>
    var query = from dbCust in db.Customers
            select dbcust;

    foreach (Customer cust in query)
    {
       (templist.add(cust)
    }

   return new list<Customer>(templist);
```

So i call for like `customers = dbmethod();` it should return the new list and the copies of templist.

But when i try to use the list i get the following error when i try to access the accounts in a customer:

> The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection."

Comment: Well...you...are disposing the dbcontext there with the `using` statement.

Comment: I've removed thank you notes from your post (as they don't add any information about the problem). Please edit your post and make sure code is correct - as it posted now there is no way you get it to run to reach runtime error.

Comment: You're trying to accesss the accounts nav property after dbcontext is disposed

Comment: When i use the return new list<Customer>(templist); does it not make a copy of it so i can use after i disposed of the db connection ?

Comment: @MattiasGreger See if the answer helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to access the accounts property after the context is disposed, you can try to use the Include method

```
using (var db = new dbcontext())
{
  return db.Customers.Include("Accounts").ToList();
```

Please read

[Loading related entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx)

[About the Using keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bwa4xa9(v=vs.110).aspx)
 [and Disposing the context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11317028/3596441)

Comment: Worked fine, Thank you very much. Dont know how or why but it fixed my problem =)

Comment: When you use Include, Entity Framework "includes" the related properties in to the object graph

Comment: As far as i understand since i Entity Framework created the tables for me shouldnt it understand that the accounts belong to the customer and return them without having to tell it to?

Comment: I have added some links on the answer, there are many more resources, if you found this answer useful, please put the checkmark :)